# Android Какой размер картинки для ListView

Tags: android, listview, изображения, android-drawable

Подскажите какой размер картинки для ListView использовать и в какой(их) папках хранить?

Использую 128*128 пикселей и храню в папке drawable. У меня все корректно отображается. Но будет ли правильнее подогнать размер для разных устройств и разбросать по папкам drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi ??? И какой размер использовать? Будет ли размер 128*128 отображаться на Android 2... или Android 3... или Android 4... ??? Может использовать размер больше чем 128*128 ???

Спасибо за комментарии!

Comment: Изучите https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: Что это за картинки, иконки? Для иконок есть заранее определенные в гайдлайнах размеры для каждой плотности экрана. "Подгонять" под разные экраны надо, так как для списка очень важна оптимизация и расходы ресурсов на масштабирование ее не улучшат.

Comment: В списке будут иконки. Вот и хотел бы узнать максимально и минимально допустимые размеры для них. Пока не нашел какие размеры!     Я так понимаю это в bitmap ложить?      xhdpi: 2.0, hdpi: 1.5, mdpi:1.0(baseline), ldpi: 0.75. А для xxhdpi и xxxhdpi какой размер?

Comment: что значит - "в bitmap ложить" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По иконкам [есть гайдлайны](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-app-shortcut-icons) (как и на все прочие элементы интерфейса).

Стандартный размер иконки на основном экране - 48dp, а иконки экшенбара и других системных панелей - 24dp (с учетом пространства вокруг изображения по 2dp с каждой стороны).
Для плотности экрана mdpi принимается коэффициент - 1.0, это значит, что 1dp = 1px (пиксель).

Соответственно для прочих плотностей вычисляется умножением значения dp на коэффициент, получаем размер в пикселях:

- 36x36 (0.75x) LDPI - res/drawable-ldpi
- 48x48 (1.0х) MDPI - res/drawable-mdpi
- 72x72 (1.5x) HDPI - res/drawable-hdpi
- 96x96 (2.0x) XHDPI - res/drawable-xhdpi
- 144x144 (3.0x) XXHDPI - res/drawable-xxdpi
- 192x192 (4.0x) XXXHDPI - res/drawable-xxxdpi

В своих айтемах вы можете использовать и другой размер иконки, если это требуется, главное соблюдать коэффициенты для плотностей. Сама иконка для каждой плотности должна иметь такой размер, чтобы **располагаться на экране "как есть"**, без масштабирования (размеры заданы параметром `wrap_content`).
Это связано с тем, что на масштабирование тратится значительный ресурс и слабое устройство может "упасть" по Out of Memory Error, кроме того при масштабировании может теряться качество изображения.

Создавать иконки рекомендуется в формате PNG, в таком виде и хранить в ресурсах проекта.

Отображение иконок на экране не зависит от версии Android и на версии 2.3 и на 7.1 они будут иметь одинаковый размер при одинаковых параметрах экрана.

Так же, если есть возможность рекомендуется использовать [векторный формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621991/177345). Для векторных изображений следует указывать размер на экране в относительных величинах, например - 48х48dp,  вместо `wrap_content`.

Так же нелишним будет ознакомится [с официальным гайдом](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) по поддержке экранов разной плотности

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет разбросать картинки по папкам, поскольку на разных устройствах с разным расширением экрана и плотностью, они будут выглядеть по-разному. Если же для каждой конфигурации будет своя картинка, то в общем на всех устройствах она будет выглядеть одинаково.