# тормозит RecyclerView при прокрутке из-за ImageView CardView

Tags: android, recyclerview, imageview, cardview, recyclerview.adapter

При прокрутке списка всего из 3-х элементов, сильно тормозит RecyclerView.
Item в RecyclerView Это CardView. Разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_item"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:src="@drawable/hot1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_card"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardHolder> {

    private List<String> titles;
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

    public CardAdapter(List<String> list, View.OnClickListener c) {
        this.titles = list;
        this.clickListener = c;
    }

    @Override
    public CardAdapter.CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_main_fragment, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        return new CardHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardAdapter.CardHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindTitle(titles.get(position));
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                holder.bindImage(R.drawable.hot1);
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.bindImage(R.drawable.medium1);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.bindImage(R.drawable.lazy1);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int id) {
        return titles.get(id);
    }

    static class CardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvCardItem;
        private ImageView ivCardItem;
        private String str;

        CardHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvCardItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_card);
            ivCardItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_card);
        }

        void bindTitle(String s) {
            this.str = s;
            tvCardItem.setText(str);
        }

        void bindImage(int id) {
            ivCardItem.setImageResource(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Я разобрался в каком месте возникают проблемы:

```
void bindImage(int id) {
    ivCardItem.setImageResource(id);
}
```

Но:

1) я не понимаю **почему именно** из-за этого тормозит, если этот метод вызывается всего 3 раза, чтобы привязать картинку к каждому из 3-х элементов. (проверил через Log)

2) если тормозит из-за размера ресурса (1000 х 1000 пикселей), то почему не тормозит когда я просто в xml пропишу путь к картинке (которая тоже 1000 х 1000 пикселей)

3) и как мне все-таки программно реализовать для каждого item свою картинку? Картинки лежат в drawable.

Добавил разметку, которая содержит RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="torin.dmitry.todolist.fragments.StartFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ничего криминального в коде не заметил. Попробуйте следующее: 1. Уберите верхний `LinearLayout` из разметки. Он лишний. Пусть `CardView` будет корневым. 2. Если ваши ресурсы не нарезаны под все dpi, то поместите их в папку `drawable-nodpi`. 3. Не используйте `weight`. Раз у вас есть точные размеры родителя (`CardView`), то вы можете сами вычислить и точные размеры для ваших `TextView ` и `ImageView`.

Comment: @eugeneek Да, начинаю склоняться к тому что проблема в разметке. Убрал лишний LinearLayout, убрал жесткое ограничение размера у CardView, после чего убрал весы - в результате каждый Item в RecyclerView растянулся до неприличных размеров (картинка по центру вертикально, а текст в самом низу) НО! - пропали тормоза. Мистика... Однако если вернуть жестко заданный размер - тормоза возвращаются. Любой способ, который приводит к фиксированному размеру CardView заставляет список тормозить. На всякий случай приведу еще разметку где RecyclerView

Comment: Должен быть `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` у `CardView` и `android:adjustViewBounds=true` у `ImageView`.

Comment: 1000х1000 пикселей - размер, [не приемлемый для скролящегося элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630850/177345) с скалированием (масштабированием) этого изображения. У вас ведь он не в натуральный размер выводится, тогда зачем такой огромный? Специально для этой проблемы используются [ресурсы с квалификаторами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345), тогда каждому экрану соответствествует оптимальный размер

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, полезное замечание. В итоге проблема оказалась именно в этом. Я просто думал что если у меня разрешение на устр-ве 1080 х 1920 и с img 1000 х 1000 в качестве Item все будет хорошо. Оказалось - нет.

Comment: @pavlofff Размер конечно имеет значение, но и с таким размером список не будет тормомозить если всё остальное сделано правильно. Иначе как сделать такой список с маленькими картинками, чтобы они отображались без потерь качества на full hd дисплеях? Или даже на 4K.

Comment: @eugeneek Все зависит от размера оперативной памяти и мощности процессора, наивно расчитывать, что вашим приложением будут пользоваться только на мощных устройствах. Масштабирование изображения - огромная нагрузка на устройство, особенно, когда их несколько, поэтому первое правило оптимизации списков - изображения должны быть оригинального размера. О проблемах маленьких картинок на экранах большого разрешения не совсем понял, есть квалификаторы xxhdpi, xxxhdpi, размещаете там изображения нужного размера и качества, какие потери?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Архитектурно все написано правильно - ну то есть кэширование картинок работает (иначе `RecyclerView` и не позволил бы написать). Проблема в скорости начальной загрузки картинок. Варианта 2:

1. Уменьшить размеры картинок, прогнав их например через [ThumbmnailUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) или вручную предварительно уменьшив их. Размер 1000*1000 явно великоват для отображения в списке (по любому)
2. Настроить загрузку картинок в фоновом потоке, можно самому написать (ничего суперсложного нет) или использовать [universal-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) или [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), я лично предпочитаю universal-image-loader

Answer (score 1):

Создайте класс, например `Drawables`

```
class Drawables {

private int pic_value;

static final Drawables[] mDrawable = {

        new Drawables(R.drawable.pic1),
        new Drawables(R.drawable.pic2),
        new Drawables(R.drawable.pic3),
        new Drawables(R.drawable.pic4),
        new Drawables(R.drawable.pic5),
};

private Drawables(int pic_value) {
    this.pic_value= pic_value;
}

int getPic_value() {
    return pic_value;
}
```

И далее в адаптере:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardHolder> {

private List<Drawables> picture;

public CardAdapter(List<String> pic) {
    this.picture = pic;
}

@Override
public CardAdapter.CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_main_fragment, parent, false);

    return new CardHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardAdapter.CardHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.ivCardItem.setBackgroundResource(picture.get(position).getPic_value());
    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return picture.size();
}

static class CardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvCardItem;
    private ImageView ivCardItem;
    private String str;

    CardHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvCardItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_card);
        ivCardItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_card);
    }
}
```

}

Таким образом каждый пункт у вас будет соотноситься к картинке которая соответствует этому пункту.

Comment: Не помогло, но код стал красивее

Comment: @torin попробуйте верхний `LinearLayout` заменить на `NestedScrollView`

Comment: @torin также в `RecyclerView` добавьте `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`